# Support for datetime data type in RedisGraph

Tags: redisgraph

I would like to host a node property of type datetime and need to utilize it in the where clause of cypher for filtering and selecting nodes based on datetime ranges.

https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/cypher_support/ mentions the datetime is not supported and is there any limitation or issues with storing it as milliseconds instead ? Has anyone came across such situation and how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The only time-related function RedisGraph currently supports is `timestamp()`, which returns the current epoch time in milliseconds.

It, and all other RedisGraph integers, is stored as a signed 64-bit integer. If your program can produce timestamps, you can safely store them as integer properties and perform any filtering you wish on them.